# How validate generic type in Spring

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I have universal generic class and I would like to validate depend on type variables.
The definition of generic type is:

```
public class MyClass<K> {
    @NotNull
    private K id;
}
```

Controller definition:

```
public void save(@RequestBody @Valid MyClass<@NotBlank String> id)
```

But @NotBlank validator is not executed. There is any possibility to validate such generic type?

Comment: I don't know if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513910/spring-3-2-validation-on-generic-types

Comment: It's not the same problem, because NotNull validation is working normally. Problem is only with NotBlank.